# Issues in setting secondary properties to a document using cmis 1.1

Tags: alfresco, cmis

I am trying to add the secondary properties (title,description) programmatically to a document in Alfresco using CMIS 1.1.

code snippet:

```
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, fileName);
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document,P:cm:titled"); 
properties.put(PropertyIds.SECONDARY_OBJECT_TYPE_IDS, "P:cm:titled");
properties.put("cm:title", "test title");
properties.put("cm:description", "description of document");
```

The code results in successful upload of the document to the Alfresco site without any issues,but the title and description are empty in Alfresco UI.

I also tried setting the tags to a document as well. Tags were also empty  in alfresco site.

The code snippet

```
document = parentFolder.createDocument(properties, contentStream, null);
AlfrescoDocument alfDoc = (AlfrescoDocument) document;
Map<String, Object> properties1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
tags.add("cmisTag");
tags.add("testTag");
properties1.put("cm:taggable",tags);
alfDoc.updateProperties(properties1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first look I thought it might be that you are setting your secondary object type IDs property to a single value instead of an array, but then I looked at [my gist](https://gist.github.com/jpotts/7242070) on this and I am also using a String instead of an array of Strings.

Now I notice that you are using AlfrescoDocument which means you are using the OpenCMIS Extension. If you are using CMIS 1.1 you do NOT want to use the OpenCMIS extension. Just use the regular OpenCMIS library without it. Use Document instead of AlfrescoDocument.

Comment: Hey Jeff,

I had removed the cmis extension part from my code and now I am able to set the title, description for my folders and documents :)

Now I have a question whether tags could be added to my document via cmis 1.1. Kindly explain me how tagging works in cmis 1.1.

Comment: Tagging does not work via CMIS. You'll have to use the Alfresco REST API for tags.

Comment: Thanks Jeff..I implemented tagging using Rest API.